# Saving Images from a URL in selenium (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, sendkeys

So, I finally completed my simple script to fetch some image links from some site. Now, the problem is that selenium isn't saving those images. No, I don't want screenshots, they are not serving the purpose. Screenshot leaves a lot of white space as it see in it's own resolution.

Anyways, I've tried this to send "ctrl+S" and then press "Enter" :

```
saveas = ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('s').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.ENTER)
        saveas.perform()
```

Now, what am I doing wrong here? the link to image :  http://imgcomic.naver.net/webtoon/654817/44/20160314180903_2cfdd685f7e4f2c93a54e819898d6fb1_IMAG01_2.jpg

Comment: I cant't access the link you attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webdriver takes whole page screenshot. However you can try by cropping the image as per your element dimensions. Below java code will helps you

```
 driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"));   
    //Get entire page screenshot
    File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
    //Get the location of element on the page
    Point point = image.getLocation();
    //Get width and height of the element
    int imageWidth = image.getSize().getWidth();
    int imageHeight = image.getSize().getHeight();
    //Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
    BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), imageWidth,
            imageHeight);
    ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);
    //Copy the element screenshot to disk
    FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("E:\\selenium_desk\\GoogleLogo_screenshot1.png"));
    driver.close();
```

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score -1):

You can create another instance of webdriver just with the image URL and take screenshot. Not ideal, but works for me most of the time.

```
fb = webdriver.Firefox()
fb.set_window_size(1200,2000) # Make sure the browser size is large enough
fb.get('IMAGE_URL')
imgs = fb.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
imgs[0].screenshot('screenshot.png')
```

Then you can use Pillow to convert the image to jpg if size matters.